# Are javascript .map function callbacks async

Tags: javascript, dictionary, asynchronous, callback

In this example will the order always log the same?  Is this guaranteed?  I'm trying to figure out if the callback function in .map is async in that one callback is guaranteed to complete before the next iteration starts.

```
var a = [];

for (var x = 1; x<100000; x++) {
    a.push(x);
}

var a2 = a.map((item) => {
   // --- Some Work that takes random amount of time ---
   console.log(item); 

})
```

Comment: Order is the same, guaranteed. No they are not async. Just read [any documentation out there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description), please.

Comment: `.map` is not async, but logic inside *can* be (if you call it)

Comment: Order is the same, provided that you're not changing the array in the callback.

Comment: They are called in order and synchronously, however inside them other async functions can be called and they might call callbacks or resolve Promises out-of-order.

Comment: `map()` is equivalent to using a `for` loop to iterate over the array.

Comment: @Teemu Even if you change the array in the callbacks, it still guarantees iterating in order (EG. if you do `(item,i)` then `i` will increase on each iteration), although if you increase the length of the array it won't visit new elements.

Comment: @Paulpro I was thinking about splicing the array too.

Comment: @Teemu `i` is still guaranteed to strictly increase, so I would say the iteration still happens in order, but you might visit elements that are different than what was in that position when you started the `map` and you might not visit some elements at all if they've been removed.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I did read that documentation, Patrick, but it says each callback is called in order, but does say it completes in order.  I just wanted to be sure.  Thanks for the responses.